# Hot to collect the latitude and longitude values when i dial a particular on my phone dial pad

Tags: android

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {

        String phonenum = intent.getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        if (phonenum.equals("111")) {

            locationmanager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationlistener);
            Toast.makeText(context, "The Gps values are..." + lon, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
}

private static LocationListener locationlistener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
        lon = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    }
};
```

hi,
when i dial 111 on my dial pad my app which is pre installed on my device should toast the latitude and logitude values.I tried a sample app which displays toast message on dial of 111 making use of broadcast receiver.Above is the code which i tried.Can any help me how to get the latitude and logitude values from this fucntion.

Comment: Have you searched for how to fetch location in android ?

Comment: i already got the location values with another app.my requirement is to collect the location values on dial of 111 .

Comment: So, why not just execute that code in onReceive ?

Comment: tried same thing in onreceive.but no use

Comment: Is the onReceive method executed ?

Comment: ya onReceive method is executed.

Comment: So, until unless you show us the code that is execute in onReceive how will anyone be able to help you out ?

Comment: posted the code above what i did in onReceive

Comment: So, I think you'll start receiving location here : 

` lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
 lon = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());` considering you've added permission for location in your app.

Comment: added the permissions

Answer (score 0):

```
private Location getLastBestLocation() {
Location locationGPS = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
Location locationNet = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

long GPSLocationTime = 0;
if (null != locationGPS) { GPSLocationTime = locationGPS.getTime(); }

long NetLocationTime = 0;

if (null != locationNet) {
    NetLocationTime = locationNet.getTime();
}

if ( 0 < GPSLocationTime - NetLocationTime ) {
    return locationGPS;
}
else {
    return locationNet;
}}
```